# Why does this script not work occassionally when in runtime?

Tags: applescript

Sometimes when i run my script, the error "File some object wasn't found" yet it works most of the time (I haven't changed the path at all).

```
display dialog "Virus is downloading." buttons "Stop Download" with title "Malware Initiating" with icon alias ((path to me) & "Contents:Resources:Spy.icns" as string)
```

The error is for the icon and it highlights ((path to me) as the error.

Can anyone tell me why this happens? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see you did:

```
((path to me) & "Contents:Resources:Spy.icns" as string)
```

What I found on the net as a correct solution:

```
((path to me as text) & "::")
```

The difference is that in your case, you are letting your script decide what datatype to use at (path to me) and then convert it to string, while the net's version decides in the code that it should be text in advance.

Usually your version goes well. The system has enough time to interpret what's needed. What I noticed with applescript, is that it often just hangs up on itself if the system is busy doing stuff. So putting some matters(like type conversion) into your algorithm makes it more stable.

So to make it more clear what happens behind the scenes.
Your code:

1. Take path to script as 'path type'
2. Take text "Contents:Resources:Spy.icns"
3. Add 1 and 2 together
4. Take selection and make it text

Net's code:

1. Take path to script as 'path type'
2. Make path to script text
3. Take text "Contents:Resources:Spy.icns"
4. Add 2 and 3 together

Slight difference, but sometimes definitely noticeable.

I hope this works for you :)

Comment: so would it be suitable for this command as well

`-set appLocation to path to me as string
    
-set theFile to appLocation & "Contents:Troll.mp3"
    
-tell application "Finder" to open file theFile` 

so i would change string to text

Comment: String and text are synonymous in AppleScript :)

Comment: No problem! Have fun with the language. I'm learning this weird language myself since a month or so, I'm amazed what you can do with it :)

Comment: aha yea it is pretty great